# How to uninstall old version of android sdk build tools?

Tags: android

I just downloaded the latest version of Android studio (android-studio-bundle-135.1629389.exe).  Finished installing it and started the SDK manager.

Under Tools, I see Android SDK Build-tools 21.1.1 and 21.1.2 were installed. I want to uninstall 21.1.1.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do that? You can have as many versions as you want installed at the same time. PD: Anyways If you want to do it, you can do it in the SDK Manager

Answer (score 4):

Check the checkbox next to the item to uninstall, then click the "Delete 1 package..." button in the lower-right corner of your SDK Manager window:

[image: SDK Manager]

That will bring up a confirmation dialog. If you proceed, the package will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply open SDK Manager and then in new window you will see all updates and tools which you installed or which ones you didn't. Just find there right one and select it and delete.